# How to use helper methods of one XCTestCase subclass in another XCTestCase subclass?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xctest

I have two XCTestCase subclasses,

1. `@interface SessionTest : XCTestCase`
2. `@interface UserTest : XCTestCase`

In `SessionTest` class I am having helper method `-(BOOL)Login;`

I want to use this method in `UserTest` class, can someone tell me how to achieve this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the third class:

```
@interface TestHelper : NSObject
```

implement `-(BOOL)Login` as method of `TestHelper` and use it from `SessionTest` and `UserTest`.

As possible solution you can inherit `UserTest` from `SessionTest`:

```
@interface UserTest : SessionTest
```

Comment: How does your second solution work because all the Test Case classes have .m files and no .h

Comment: .h file absence doesn't relate to inheritance in any way. @interface just used in .m file. But the actions still are the same